# Handle exit command executed by embedded Tcl runtime

Tags: tcl, interpreter

I have a small shell application that embeds [Tcl](http://tmml.sourceforge.net/doc/tcl/category-index.html) to execute some set of Tcl code. The Tcl interpreter is initialized using Tcl_CreateInterp. Everything is very simple:

1. user types Tcl command
2. the command gets passed to Tcl_Eval for evaluation
3. repeat

But if a user types 'exit', which is a valid Tcl command, the whole thing - Tcl interpreter and my shell application - exit automatically.

Q: is there any way I can catch this exit signal coming from Tcl interpreter. I really would like not to check every user command. I tried [Tcl_CreateExitHandler](http://tmml.sourceforge.net/doc/tcl/CExit.html), but it didn't work.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Fixed the title and removed references to "tcllib" because a standardized library *for* Tcl [is commonly known by that name](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/).  What you seem to really refer to is embedding of Tcl runtime into your program.

Comment: `Tcl_CreateExitHandler` is for trapping exits and releasing resources (e.g., database connections) that otherwise hang around nastily. It can't stop an exit from happening.

Comment: That's actually exactly what I want to do - release resources on exit. Why wouldn't `Tcl_CreateExitHandler` work in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Tcl_CreateExitHandler` works fine. The problem was that I added a `printf` into the handler implementation and the output didn't show up on the terminal. So I thought it hasn't been called. However, by the time this handler is executed there is no `stdout` any more. Running `strace` on the application shows that the handler is being executed fine.

Another solution to this problem can be to use [atexit](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atexit) and process the exit event there.

Answer (score 9):

Get rid of the command

```
rename exit ""
```

Or redefine it to let the user know it's disabled:

```
proc exit {args} { error "The exit command is not available in this context" }
```

Also worth considering is running the user's code in a [safe interp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/interp.htm#M10) instead of in the main shell. Doing so would allow you to control exactly what the user has access to.

You might also be able to create a child interp (non-safe) and just disable the exit command for that interp.

Lastly, you could just rename exit to something else, if you're only trying to avoid users typing it by mistake:

```
namespace eval ::hidden {}
rename exit ::hidden::exit
```

Comment: That can work. But I still would like to preserve the 'exit' call.

Comment: If you want to have exit available to you, but not to the user, I'd recommend the safe interp route.

Comment: @jk. In general, I'd agree with that. The obvious caveat is that he might want to allow users the full power of the Tcl shell, but doesn't want them to exit the program by accident. Its hard to tell from the question whether this is true or not.

Comment: Yes, definitively the last comment: I would like not to limit users in what they can type. Is there any way I can send the ctrl+D signal in the custom exit procedure?

Comment: Why do you need to send the ctrl+D in the custom exit procedure? If you move the exit command "out of the way" (via rename), you can still call it.

Answer (score 2):

Rename the `exit` command:

```
rename exit __exit

proc exit {args} {
    puts -nonewline "Do you really want to exit? (y/n) "
    flush stdout
    gets stdin answer
    if {$answer == "y"} {
        __exit [lindex $args 0]
    }
}
```

This way, when the user type `exit`, he/she will execute your custom exit command, in which you can do anything you like.

Comment: Thanks, Hai. However, this still doesn't resolve my problem - if `exit` is called from Tcl my whole C app closes unconditionally. I still need to clean up some resources on exit.